# Postgres, operation are slow

Tags: postgresql

My Postgres queries are slow on the table records.

A simple request like that can take 15 seconds ! 
The result: 32k (on 1.5 millions)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM project.records
WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day'
```

I have an index on created_at (which is a timestamp)

What can I do to manage this ? Is it my table who is too big ?

Comment: An index can't help with a time range. Are your rows very large?

Comment: Yes. It contains a full web page and lots of metadatas. Is it a problem? It thought that an unused column was not counted in the query.

Comment: Even if you only need 1 byte you need an I/O operation to get it. If fast counting is important, consider moving the large columns to a separate table.

Comment: We need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to answer that question.

Comment: @Andomar: of course an index can help with a time range. Why do you think it doesn't

Comment: @Andomar: It depends on the type of the index. E.g. a hash index indeed wouldn't help a range query. But a B tree well can.

Comment: @Andomar you were right. I removed the large columns to another table, and I did a `VACUUM ANALYZE`. 

Now the query take 400ms.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Andomar, I removed the large columns to another table.

I made sure to do a `VACUUM ANALYZE` to really clean the table.

Now the query take 400ms.